# xcode organizer download button di

Tags: xcode, download, organizer

I am trying to copy data files of an ios (5.1) app from an iphone, with Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile, to a MacBook. XCode 4.4.1 is used on the MacBook. With the iphone connected, under Organizer, Devices, the connected iPhone and the app are detected. However, when the app is selected, no files are displayed in the 'Data Files in Sandbox' section and the Download button is disabled.

What would be the possible causes? The MacBook used is not the developer's machine. Can this method used to copy app data files to any MacBook with XCode installed (but no source code)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Xcode Organizer to copy files from an iPhone to a non-developer machine. The Organizer shows only apps for which a valid provisioning profile is available in Xcode.

But you can do it with iTunes if you connect the device, select it and go to the bottom of the "Apps" tab. There you see all Apps that support file sharing. If you select one of the apps, you can see and download the contents of the Documents directory.

To enable file sharing for your app, you have to add the key

```
UIFileSharingEnabled (Application supports iTunes file sharing)
```

to the Info.plist and set the Boolean value to YES.